# Phusion Passenger setting PassengerPreStart does not activate using service httpd start

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I'm running Phusion Passenger on RHEL, hosting a Rails application.

I can successfully start up a passenger instance on Apache startup using the Passenger setting `PassengerPreStart`, but only if I start up Apache using `apachectl start`.

If I start up Apache using the RHEL convention of `service httpd start`, then `PassengerPreStart` is not executed.  That is, no passenger instance is loaded on Apache startup.

I've compared the two scripts (`apachectl` and the `service httpd` script) for differences but can't find anything different between them that would account for the difference in behavior.

I could write a init script to start up Apache using `apachectl`, but thought first I would ask if anyone has seen this difference on how `apachectl` and `service http` interact with Apache modules, and in particular, with Passenger's `PassengerPreStart` setting and explain it.